# Is there any way of getting the content of an e-mail given a URI on Android?

Tags: android, email

I have an URI like this: email://messages/0/INBOX/7154
Is there any way of getting the content of this e-mail (i.e. the body) either through the Android SDK or through a third-party library?
Cheers

Comment: There is no `email://` scheme in Android.

Comment: @CommonsWare: I see, I got the URI from the K9 e-mail client from the EMAIL_RECEIVED intent.

Comment: I think there's a Google Group or something for K9. If they are documenting that broadcast, they should be documenting what to do with the `Uri`.

Comment: search for content resolver.  I was thinking you wanted email attachment

Answer (score 1):

[This thread](https://groups.google.com/group/android-beginners/browse_thread/thread/d19e1bab1d91febb?pli=1) leads me to believe that while there was (and is?) a way to listen for SMS-received intents, there is no way to read received email.

Answer (score -2):

I think there 's no way to deal with your problem. Maybe you can change another way.